# SMESERVER: Mail not receiving, 550 v=spf1 a -all

Tags: linux, centos, email, email-server, email-bounces

SMESERVER install has been working find for an age then this morning "The error that the other server returned was: 550 v=spf1 a -all", can anyone 'point' me in the right direction to resolving this issue.  There is an obvious element of urgency.

From my own mind 550 is access denied and SPF would indicate a DNS problem, am I right?  Still have no idea on how to resolve it though.

also getting a "bash: 22: command not found", when trying to SSH in.

Any guidance GREATLY appreciated

Stu

Comment: You should have opened a bug report with SME Server prior to posting here. Where is the link to your bug report?

Comment: Whether a bug or a fault, there was a problem.  Filing a bug report is not helpful to the current situation, response times are slow.  This was a server outage for all my customers that required immediate attention.  I do appreciate you taking the time to respond though, thank you @michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a bug, can be fixed with the following config changes.

Try The following:

```
config delprop qpsmtpd SBLList
config setprop qpsmtpd RBLList zen.spamhaus.org
signal-event email-update
```

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. I've undeleted and merged your answer with the original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yip you was right, it was the SPAM blacklist, I did find it just hadn't updated the overflow.  All my customers went down with the problem.